# Are rainbows a reaction from earths natural release of gas after a rain?

Tags: meteorology, weather-forecasting, carbon-cycle

In my studies, Ive dropped a limestone or porous stone into water, with salt and sugar.
The results where an impressive light show of color flashes.
With the Earths natural release of gas, these colors of gas would rise up causing a dome shape and the pressure caused by the moisture hold it in one spot till it evaporates.
The sun beams enhancing the show of color.
Perhaps the reason Israel only shows 4 parts of the colors and not all 7.
Depending on Location, surface material.
-Just sharing a new way to look at Rainbows.

Answer (score 3):

[Rainbows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow) are the result of water droplets in the atmosphere reflecting, refracting and dispersing light resulting in a spectrum of light in an arched shape in the sky.

The water droplets in the atmosphere act the same way prisms do when they split white light into its component colors, hence the spectrum of light.

The fact that the phenomenon is called a rainbow is due to rainbows generally appearing after certain rainfall events, when the atmosphere contains water droplets.

Comment: An even better link is Les Cowley's remarkable [Atmospheric Optics](https://www.atoptics.co.uk) site.

Comment: Rainbows can equally occur before the rain.  At temperate latitudes where weather moves from west to east, a pre-rain rainbow would occur in the morning when the Sun is in the east and rain to the west.  More people are looking in the afternoon when the rainbow would appear after the rain has moved through.